# SharedPreferences can get data when app under debug mode. But when i try to run app normally, SharedPreferences can not get data which i stored

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I store a string data in SharedPreferences and app receive a notification.

After click the notification, app will start and try to get data from SharedPreferences.

The problem is: when i debug this app, activity can get data from SharedPreferences.
But when i run this app normally, activity can not get data.

Pls help, thanks

Comment: what do you mean by running the app normally?

Comment: Are you commiting your shared preference data ?

Comment: show your code here, and what is the difference your doing here for debugging and normal .

Comment: u should show some particular code to help you out.

Comment: do you store the shared preference in broadcast receiver's on receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running the app normally,check the sharperence file first,maybe you have not store the data successful.and if it is normally,check you get data code.